# HDInsight cluster creation: <account> is not a valid ARM resource id

Tags: azure-hdinsight

I am attempting to create an interactive query HDInsight cluster that will allow me to execute queries over a large set of .csv files. My issue is when I attempt to create the cluster, it says my storage account "is not a valid ARM resource id". I instead created another cluster choosing the primary storage account as a 'new account (primary storage account) created by the wizard. Then added an additional azure storage account pointing to my original account that holds my csv files. Again, same error: is not a valid ARM resource id.

What is the error referring to? The name of the storage account (5 alpha characters) or how it was created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a storage account that is a part of the Azure Resource Manager (ARM). You cannot use a 'classic' storage account. In my case, I migrated the storage account to ARM and was able to create the cluster in that account.